# Opensource chat client to be integrated with Tomcat & openfire?

Tags: tomcat

I want to know if any open source client exists which i can integrate on tomcat & set it communicated with openfire for my chat needs.

I checked with 123chat but it is not free instead it gives trial version for max 10 users.

Any idea or help?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but answering so somebody may benefit.
Yes, use spark client or just install web client plugin. If you are looking for live chat, install fastpath plugin.